# Ver imagen con javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que tengo un input de tipo **file**, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario seleccione un archivo, con javascript o jquery muestre al lado la imagen, por decirlo asi una muestra de como se va a ver y guardar la imagen, ¿hay alguna forma de hacer tal cosa sin recargar la página o algo asi?, este es el codigo de mi input:

```
<input id="cover" type="file" class="form-control @error('cover') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('cover') }}" required autocomplete="off" autofocus>
```

Desde ya gracias :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tengo uno en javascript que hace ese trabajo que pides. A mí me funciona a la perfección.
Simplemente al seleccionar una imagen de tu galería, ésta te muestra en un `div`: `#preview`.

Ejemplo:

```css
 
/* Estilo de la imágen previsualizado */

#preview img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%
}
```

```html
<!-- El input -->
<input id="cover" type="file" class="form-control @error('cover') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('cover') }}" required autocomplete="off" autofocus>
<hr> 
<!-- previsualización -->
<div id="preview"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById("cover").onchange = function(e) {   
 
 // Se crea el objeto FileReader 
 let reader = new FileReader();   
 
 // Lee el archivo y se pasa a fileReader   
 reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);   
 
 // Cuando este listo ejecuta el código interno 
 reader.onload = function(){ 
  
  let preview = document.getElementById('preview'), 
  image = document.createElement('img'); 
  image.src = reader.result; 
  preview.innerHTML = ''; 
  preview.append(image);
   
 }; 

}
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias, asi funciono :)