# Como puedo guardar una foto tomada por mi cámara en un form usando $('#').val()?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, handlebars.js

Mi script en js es el siguiente:

```javascript
function activarCamera() {
    const constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            width: 468, height: 350
        }
    };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(function (stream) {
            document.getElementById('camera').srcObject = stream;
        }).catch(function () {
            alert('could not connect stream');
        });
}

function fotoTomada() {
    // freeze camera so user can preview pic
    const $video = document.querySelector("#camera");
    $video.pause();
    // swap button sets
    document.getElementById('pre_boton').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('post_botones').style.display = '';
}

function cancelarFotoTomada() {

    const $video = document.querySelector("#camera");

    $video.play();

    document.getElementById('pre_boton').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('post_botones').style.display = 'none';
}

function guardarFoto() {
    const $video = document.querySelector("#camera"),
        $canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");

    document.getElementById('camera').srcObject.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
        track.stop();
    });

    let contexto = $canvas.getContext("2d");

    $canvas.width = 350;
    $canvas.height = 300;
    contexto.drawImage($video, 0, 0, $canvas.width, $canvas.height);

    let foto = $canvas.toDataURL(); //Esta es la foto, en base 64
    document.getElementById('muestra').innerHTML = '<img id="foto_perfil" class="thumbnail" src="' + foto + '"/>';
    document.getElementById('pre_boton').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('post_botones').style.display = 'none';
    $("#foto").val(foto);


}

function desactivarCamera() {
    document.getElementById('camera').srcObject.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
        track.stop();
    });
}
```

Como lo puedo guardar en un input(que tipo de input sería?) para enviarlo por el formulario

Comment: puede leer el valor que contiene el atributo type del input; luego creas otro input tipo text/hiden al que le agregar en el valor el type que leiste anteriormente y lo insertas al final del formulario ...

Comment: Me podrías dar un ejemplo? Por favor

Comment: la parte de investigación es la que te toca hacer... si una vez tienes algún problema implementándola; entonces nos traes el código y te podemos ayudar.

Comment: $("#fotoGuardada").val($("#foto").val()); de esta forma esta correcto?

Comment: no en JavaScript obtienes el valor de un atributo con `document.getElementById('demo-1')..getAttribute('src');` pero eso ya es otra pregunta ...

Comment: Okey amigo muchas gracias

Comment: Te podria ayudar éste código que respondí? https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/492211/155688

Comment: Si, muchas gracias, pero como podría controlar el tamaño de la imagen en la previsualización?

Comment: El tamaño de una imagen, así como el de cualquier elemento del documento, puedes configurarlo con CSS. Puedes establecer un ancho y alto mínimo y máximo, según tus requerimientos. Para tal fin te aconsejaría colocar una clase al elemento de imagen que estás creando, y en el CSS configuras las propiedades de esa clase.